# Error while trying to throw new Exception in class' constructor

Tags: php, class, constructor, exception

I have this class

```
namespace core;

class Entity {

    private $type;

    public function __construct($type, $source=null){
        if($this::isValidType($type)){
            $this->type = $type;
        }else{
            throw new Exception("'".$type."' is not a valid type of entity.");
        }
    }


    private static function isValidType($type){
        return in_array($type, array(
            'Thing',
        ));
    }
}
```

Then I use this code:

```
$thing = new core\Entity('Not a Thing');
```

And I expect it to show `"Not a Thing" is not a valid Type of entity` but instead I get

> Fatal Error: Class 'core\Exception' not found in {root/to/my/file} on line {line}`.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `namespace core;` so using `throw new Exception` means `Exception` class under current `namespace`, Instead use `throw new \Exception`

**Change this to:**

```
throw new Exception("'".$type."' is not a valid type of entity.");
```

**This:**

```
throw new \Exception("'".$type."' is not a valid type of entity.");
```